# Python 2.7 passing an object to a class function

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, parameter-passing

I'm trying to test out my 2D coordinate and vector classes in python. Here is the code where the vector and coordinate classes are defined:

```
class coord(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def resolve(endCoord):
        return vector((self.x-endCoord.x),(self.y-endCoord.y))

class vector(object):
    def __init__(self, xTrans, yTrans):
        self.xTrans = xTrans
        self.yTrans = yTrans
        self.magnitude = sqrt((self.xTrans**2)+(self.yTrans**2))
```

I then test these with the statements below:

```
inp1 = raw_input("Please enter the first coordinate: ")
inp2 = raw_input("Please enter the second coordinate: ")
coord1 = coord(int(inp1[0]), int(inp1[2]))
coord2 = coord(int(inp2[0]), int(inp2[2]))
vector1 = coord1.resolve(coord2)
print "Vector magnitude is "+str(vector1.magnitude)
```

I get a problem with the line:

```
vector1 = coord1.resolve(coord2)
```

where it throws this error:

```
exceptions.TypeError: resolve() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I don't know how to fix it. The inp1 I give is "0,0" (without the quote marks) and for inp2 I give "5,5" (again no quotes)

I think it might be an issue either with giving an object as a function argument or the fact I am giving a coordinate as a function parameter, when the function is inside the coordinate class?

I don't really know, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `resolve` should be `self`.

```
class coord(object):
    ...
    def resolve(self, endCoord):
        return vector((self.x-endCoord.x),(self.y-endCoord.y))
```

Answer (score 1):

All methods (like functions but in Classes) accept the first parameter as `self`, as shown in your `__init__()` method.

```
def resolve(endCoord):
```

Should be

```
def resolve(self, endCoord):
```

See the [relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).